# Issue with makeglossaries not surpporting negative thinspace

Tags: glossaries

I have a glossary entry using a negative thinspace ("\!"), but it seems that `makeglossaries` is generating wrong code. I filed a bug report, but maybe there is a work-around?

Here is a minimal working example :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{foo}{text=foo,name=Foo,description={This is foo}}
\newglossaryentry{footoo}{text={foo-too},name={Foo-\!Too},description={This is foo-too}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\gls{foo}
\lipsum[1]
\gls{footoo}
\lipsum[1]

\printglossaries{}

\end{document}
```

In the glossary, at the end of the "Foo" line, there is a residual "Foo- ̈".I find `Foo-\"\relax \glsresetentrylist` in the .gls file, which, once removed, cleans the output of `pdflatex`, but the root cause is likely in the glo file which replaces the "\!" with "\"!".

Comment: never used glossary, so it's a shot in the dark... have you tried `name={Foo-{\!}Too}` ?

Comment: `!` has a special meaning in working with indexing programmes (which makeglossasries uses behind the scenes), perhaps you should give it a different name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character `!` has a special meaning in indexing programmes (which `makeglossaries` uses behind the scenes). I don't think any of them look to see if the `!` is "escaped". Instead I'd suggest giving `\!` a different name and then use that.

This seems to work

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\let\ts\!


\newglossaryentry{foo}{text=foo,name=Foo,description={This is foo}}
\newglossaryentry{footoo}{text={foo-too},name={Foo-\ts Too},description={This is foo-too}}

\makeglossaries


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\gls{foo}
\lipsum[1]
\gls{footoo}
\lipsum[1]

\printglossaries{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[daleif's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551690/48973) is correct. However, if you only need this once in your document and prefer not to create a new macro for that purpose, you can also just insert manual kerning:

```latex
\newglossaryentry{footoo}{text={foo-too},name={Foo-\kern-.1667emToo},description={This is foo-too}}
```

Comment: I have multiple entries that require this typesetting, so I'll go with the macro. Thanks for giving a look at the issue though.